# Visual Studio C# target platform x86 but nuget package seems to me x64 - error when program runs

Tags: c#, x86, 64-bit, nuget-package

I have to build x86 program. I use package from nuget (ENet-CSharp). My program is bult succesfully but when I run it I get error System.BadImageFormatException which happens due to the package is x64 (As I suppose because when I set target platform to x64 no problem at all) and my target platform is x86. So I cannot understand how to resolve this situation. How to understand what is the architecture of package from nuget? And how to get the package with the architecture I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting a specific platform it might be a good idea to use the [Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-edit-configurations?view=vs-2022) to add the x86 platform, as well as removing any other platform if these are not needed. And do the same for each project.

I think nuget use the *project platform* to get the correct dependencies, while the *platform target* in the project determines the binary format for the produced dll. But I'm no expert on the .net build system, so there might be something I missed.